# Connecting to Oracle data source via DataGrip (HR scheme)

Tags: oracle, datagrip

I downloaded schemes from this website (https://github.com/oracle-samples/db-sample-schemas/releases/tag/v21.1)

but I don't know how to work on them in the DataGrip, that is, how to connect and which user data to use for connecting to the Oracle data source (Host, SID, Port, user, password etc)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Schemas are the content. But you need a place where to place this content. So you need to create a database server first. In Docker or in the cloud. During installation, you will set the username, password, port etc

Comment: How to get Oracle database server in docker. I checked the Docker Hub and there's only and image called oraclelinux and I tried setting it up but couldn't. Is that the image I should use or should I look somewhere else?

Comment: You can build via [oraclelinux](https://hub.docker.com/_/oraclelinux) image, this Dockerfile could help: https://github.com/DataGrip/docker-env-oracle/blob/master/12.2.0.1/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schemas are the content.
And you need a place where to place this content.

So, create a database server first. You can do that via Docker or in the cloud.
Here is the Dockerfile you can use to create a docker container with the oracle database running:

https://github.com/DataGrip/docker-env-oracle/blob/master/12.2.0.1/Dockerfile

During installation, you will set the username, password, port etc